# Calculating height and add animation to full description when "read more" is clicked

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have situation where I want to animate description when is clicked on "read more". For now I have code:

```
$('.read-more').on('click', function () {
$('.description').height();
$('.description').toggleClass('visible');
$('.read-more').toggleClass('open');});
```

I'm caltulating height of description but don't know how can I animate this description when "read more" is clicked

Thanks for help

Comment: Can you show us the HTML code and it's CSS style... what's the .description element type? What's  the expected animation effect.. ?

Comment: Hello, here is sample code: https://jsfiddle.net/petekA/w8fsaek1/4/ I want effect like slideToggle ..thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

try ->

```
$('.read-more').on('click', function () {
           $('.description').css({'height':'auto','overflow':'visible'})
                 $('.read-more').toggleClass('open');
});
```

Comment: He didn't shared .open class in the fiddle ! $('.read-more').toggle(); would be enough I think...

Comment: Hello, I tried with this code but unsucsessfully: http://jsfiddle.net/petekA/w8fsaek1/12/ I use "open" class on read more button for effect on button not for description. For full description I'm using class "visible". Thanks for help